# Python - Regular Expression Assistance

Tags: python, regex

I was wondering if I could get some assistance in coming up with a regular expression. I have a file that contains a long list of various aliases and the email address that alias forwards to. The file is in a format like this:

alias:something@gmail.com 

alias2:something2@gmail.com 

alias3:something3@gmail.com 

alias4:something4@gmail.com 

alias5:something5@gmail.com

How can I write a regular expression to just grab the part before the colon (alias, alias2, etc)? Sorry if this is a painfully easy question, I'm new to Python. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need for regexps. Simply review the documentation of the string method [`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `split()` for this problem, since you have a very obvious delimiter. However, this is a solution with regular expressions:

```
lines = open(filename).readlines()
regex = re.compile("(.*):.*@gmail\.com")
aliases = [m.group(1) for m in map(lambda x: regex.match(x), lines) if m]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list-comprehension for it

```
first_parts = [
    line.split(':')[0]
    for line in file("addresses.txt").readlines()
    if ':' in line
]
```

It is similar to this

```
first_parts = []
lines = file("addresses.txt").readlines()
for lines in lines:
    if ":" in line:
        first = line.split(":")[0]
        first_parts.append(first)
```